# How should I convert an RDD of org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector to Dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-dataset

I'm struggling to understand how the conversion among RDDs, DataSets and DataFrames works.
I'm pretty new to Spark, and I get stuck every time I need to pass from a data model to another (especially from RDDs to Datasets and Dataframes).
Could anyone explain me the right way to do it?

As an example, now I have a `RDD[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector]` and I need to pass it to my machine learning algorithm, for example a KMeans (Spark DataSet MLlib). So, I need to convert it to Dataset with a single column named "features" which should contain Vector typed rows. How should I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To convert a RDD to a **dataframe**, the easiest way is to use `toDF()` in Scala. To use this function, it is necessary to import implicits which is done using the `SparkSession` object. It can be done as follows:

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = rdd.toDF("features")
```

`toDF()` takes an RDD of tuples. When the RDD is built up of common Scala objects they will be implicitly converted, i.e. there is no need to do anything, and when the RDD has multiple columns there is no need to do anything either, the RDD already contains a tuple. However, in this **special case** you need to first convert `RDD[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector]` to `RDD[(org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector)]`. Therefore, it is necessary to do a convertion to tuple as follows:

```scala
val df = rdd.map(Tuple1(_)).toDF("features")
```

The above will convert the RDD to a dataframe with a single column called features.

---

To convert to a **dataset** the easiest way is to use a case class. Make sure the case class is defined outside the Main object. First convert the RDD to a dataframe, then do the following:

```scala
case class A(features: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector)

val ds = df.as[A]
```

To show all possible convertions, to access the underlying **RDD** from a dataframe or dataset can be done using `.rdd`:

```scala
val rdd = df.rdd
```

---

Instead of converting back and forth between RDDs and dataframes/datasets it's usually easier to do all the computations using the dataframe API. If there is no suitable function to do what you want, usually it's possible to define an UDF, user defined function. See for example here: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-udfs.html

Comment: I've tried your solution, it gives me this error:

Error:(94, 32) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector]
        val df = rdd.toDF("features")

Comment: @Giuseppe It looks like you forgot to do `import sqlContext.implicits._`.

Comment: I've tried with one and both `import sqlContext.implicits._`
    `import spark.implicits._ ` but nothing changed. I've put them just after creating the contexts and session within the main. Could it be a problem of spark version? I'm using Spark 2.2.1

Comment: If it can help to discover the problem, if I transform to tuple `rdd.map(x => ("",x)).toDF()` the toDF() works. At this point I need to project only the _2 column and rename it.

Comment: @Giuseppe: That helps, the problem is due to RDD expecting a tuple. I added some more information to the answer that should help solve the issue :)

Comment: @Giuseppe: No problems, glad you sovled it :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an `Encoder`. Imports

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg
```

`RDD`:

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  linalg.Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0), linalg.Vectors.sparse(2, Array(), Array())
))
```

Conversion:

```scala
val ds = spark.createDataset(rdd)(ExpressionEncoder(): Encoder[linalg.Vector])
 .toDF("features")

ds.show
// +---------+
// | features|
// +---------+
// |[1.0,2.0]|
// |(2,[],[])|
// +---------+


ds.printSchema
// root
//  |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```