# Split a dataframe after PrefixSpan

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, data-mining, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying the prefixSpan algorithm example given below:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.PrefixSpan

val sequences = sc.parallelize(Seq(
 Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3)),
 Array(Array(1), Array(3, 2), Array(1, 2)),
 Array(Array(1, 2), Array(5)),
 Array(Array(6))
), 2).cache()

val prefixSpan = new PrefixSpan()
 .setMinSupport(0.5)
 .setMaxPatternLength(5)

val model = prefixSpan.run(sequences)
model.freqSequences.collect().foreach { freqSequence =>
  println(
    freqSequence.sequence.map(_.mkString("[", ", ", "]")).mkString("[", ", ", "]") +
    ", " + freqSequence.freq
  )
}
```

First thing is, I am not understanding `.mkString("[", ", ", "]")).mkString("[", ", ", "]"` this section because I am new to Scala. I am into python. I believe it is like lambda function.

Output is similar to following:

```
[[2]], 3
[[5]], 1
[[3]], 2
[[6]], 1
[[1]], 3
...
...
[[1], [2, 3], [2]], 1
[[1], [2, 3], [2, 1]], 1
[[1], [2, 3], [1]], 1
```

I need to create a new dataframe, if the row length greater than 1, for example following is one row to keep:

```
[[1], [2, 3], [2, 1]], 1
```

I need to create a new dataframe with the following content. The column `right` is always last element of the array([:-1]) the remainder is in `left`:

```
left        |right
------------------------
[[1], [2, 3]]   | [[2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `collect` to gather all data on the driver node, you can do all the transformations without that. The idea is to filter on the length to remove the patterns that are of length 1, split the array into two parts using `init` and `last` and then convert to a dataframe with `toDF`. Code below:

```
val df = model.freqSequences.map(_.sequence)
  .filter(_.length > 1)
  .map(a => (a.init, Array(a.last)))
  .toDF("left", "right")
```

`mkString` simply takes an array and converts it into a string with some specification on how it should look, here a `[` is put in the beginning and `]` in the end with `,` as separator. Part of the output looks as follows:

```
+-------------+--------+
|         left|   right|
+-------------+--------+
|[[1], [2, 3]]|[[2, 1]]|
|[[1], [2, 3]]|   [[1]]|
|        [[1]]|[[2, 1]]|
|   [[1], [2]]|   [[2]]|
+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: But here the type will get changed right? can we keep left and right to be :[Array[Array[Int]]] type?

Comment: @user2805885: Yes, it's possible. I changed the answer to keep the type as Array[Array[Int]] for both columns. To have the right column as only `Array[Int]` seems more natural though (to do this simply remove the `Array()` in the `map`.

Comment: Can you help me to change model.freqSequences to a data frame simlilar to above. Two columns I am expecting one is [Array[Array[Int]]] same as above another column is integer(freq). I need to view dataframe as above

Comment: @user2805885: Instead of keeping only the sequences in the first `map`, keep a tuple of those + the freq. Then perform the other transformations on the sequences only. In the `toDF`, simply add another column. If you need more details maybe you can create a new question and link to it in a comment here and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941411/prefix-span-output-formatting

Comment: I am trying to do the following and getting error:

val df = model.freqSequences.map(_.sequence).filter(_.length > 1).toDF("left")

<console>:31: error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Array[Int]]]
       val df = model.freqSequences.map(_.sequence).filter(_.length > 1).toDF("left")
I cann't filter and do a toDF?

Comment: @user2805885: The RDD must be a tuple, you can see for example my answer here on how to solve it (there it's for an `RDD[Vector]` but the solution is the same): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690159/how-shoud-i-convert-an-rdd-of-org-apache-spark-ml-linalg-vector-to-dataset/50691704#50691704